# Detecting the coordinates on an object and outputting them to the NSLog

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, coordinates, transform

How exactly would I detect the coordinates of an object, such as a view named "content", and output this to the log? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
NSLog(@"Object.x: %f, Object.y: %f", CGRectGetMinX(object.frame), CGRectGetMinY(object.frame));
```

Alternatively, you can get the center like so:

```
NSLog(@"Object.x: %f, Object.y: %f", object.center.x, object.center.y);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do

```
NSLog(@"position: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(object.center))
```

or.. what sometimes is more interesting the frame coordinates:

```
NSLog(@"frame: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(object.frame))
```